# CodeIgniter - Turn off controller function call?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I simply want to load the controller and not call a function based on the URI, so that I can then generate the page based on the following segments. ***How do I change the default behaviour to do this?*** eg.

example.com/class/function/ID >>> example.com/class/ID/ID

I thought all I needed to do was in config.php add:

```
$route['find/(:any)/(:any)'] = "find/$1/$2";
```

but this gives me a 404.

---

example.com/find/item/location

```
class Find extends CI_Controller {

private $s1;
private $s2;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->s1 = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->s2 = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->makePage();
}

function makePage()
{
    echo 'Page about ' . $this->s1 . 'in ' . $this->s2;
    //Get Data ($s1 & $s2)
    //Load View 
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured it out, needed to add another function to call (findit);

```
$route['find/(:any)/(:any)'] = "find/findit/$1/$2";
```

---

```
function findit()
{
    $this->makePage();
}
```

this post I found was very helpful: [CodeIgniter: Directing to functions with a URL segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106165/codeigniter-directing-to-functions-with-a-url-segment)